# how to convert key values of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am trying to convert the values of an array of grades of students to the alphabetical values and then I wnat to echo them. That is, I am retrieving this array

```
Array ( 
    'discipline' => 5, 
    'practicals' => 1, 
    'presentations' => 2, 
    'assignments' => 3, 
    'communication_skills' => 4, 
    'average' => 3, 
    'marks' => 25,
    'grade' => 'A'
)
```

and now want to give output as

```
discipline=>'D',
practicals => A
presentation => B+
assignments=> B
communication_skills => C
```

Is it possible to do without writing long if than else code in PHP.

Comment: what you have tried so far? add that in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of grades and then use it to show grades instead of numbers:

```
<?php

$grades = [
    1=>'A',
    2=>'B+',
    3=>'B',
    4=>'C',
    5=>'D'
];


$array = [ 
    'discipline' => 5, 
    'practicals' => 1, 
    'presentations' => 2, 
    'assignments' => 3, 
    'communication_skills' => 4, 
    'average' => 3, 
    'marks' => 25,
    'grade' => 'A'
];

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(!in_array($key, ['average','marks','grade'])){

        $array[$key] = $grades[$value];
    }

}

print_r($array);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/sCWHb

Note:- Used `in_array()` to skip columns while assigning grades.

It's because if in case more columns needs to be ignored while assigning grades then just add them to the array used inside `in_array()`. That's it and it will work fine (no other code modification needed).

Answer (score 1):

If the source of the student is a multidimensional array, then you can loop through the students skipping the overall grade and marks from the array, changing only the subject grades.

If your not using a multidimensional array, you can simply remove the first foreach loop and then change the syntax of variable names to address a single student.

```
$grades = ['a+', 'a', 'b']; //change accordingly to your grade schema

$students = []; // The source of your student array goes here if it's multidimensional

foreach($students as $student){

    foreach($student as $subject => $grade){

        if($subject == 'grade' || $subject = 'marks'){
            continue;
        }

        $student[$subject] = $grades[(int)$grade];
    }
}
```